# How to highlight header in excel using styles in python?

Tags: python, styles

I have a dataframe which looks like this.

| ID | Name | Sales | Sales2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | SAM | xxx | xxx |
| 123 | JON | xxx | xxx |

I want to produce an excel like this.

[image]

I tried using set tables but it is not working

```
styles = [{ 'props': ('background-color: green') }]
fd_final_highlight = fd_final.style.set_table_styles(styles)   
Weekly_excel= pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/xxx.....xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

fd_final_highlight.to_excel(Weekly_excel, sheet_name='Master', index=0) 

Weekly_excel.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solution is following:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"col1": [1, 2, 3], "col2": [1, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Users/xxx.....xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Master', startrow=1, header=False, index=False)

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Master']

# Set a header format
header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'fg_color': 'green'})

for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
    worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)

writer.save()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Was stuck with this for 2 days. Your answer worked for me. :D

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer:

```
df.style.set_table_styles(
[{'selector': 'th.col_heading',
  'props': [('background-color', 'yellow')]}])
```

> In your code

```
styles = [{'selector': 'th.col_heading',
  'props': [('background-color', 'yellow')]}]

fd_final.style.set_table_styles(styles)   
fd_final.to_excel(<your_path>, sheet_name='Master', index=0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I think set_table_styles is not working properly for me.

Comment: you should update your pandas